# implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to 'UIEvent *' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, uievent

Here is my relevant code:

```
UITouch *touch;         
NSArray *touches = [NSArray arrayWithObject:touch];
//The statement below throw the LLVM compiler error
[self touchesMoved:[NSSet setWithArray:touches] withEvent:UIEventTypeTouches];
```

here is the declaration of `touchesMoved:withEvent:` method:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Seems like I need to explicitly convert `UIEventTypeTouches` to `UIEvent`, how to fix that?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't call `touchesMoved:withEvent:` manually. You can implement it as a delegate method or override it in a `UIGestureRecognizer` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is complaining because UIEventTypeTouches is an NSInteger (defined in an enum) and `touchesMoved:withEvent:` is expecting a `UIEvent` object. You can probably get away with just passing `nil` for the event param:

```
[self touchesMoved:[NSSet setWithArray:touches] withEvent:nil];
```